# ubuntu cron job stopped working

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron, digital-ocean

The cron job used to working well and suddenly stopped working

```
1 * * * *  /usr/bin/python3 /home/roy/update.py
```

It can still run manually on the command line.

Then I tried to debug it by the following command:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/roy/update.py  2>&1 >> /home/roy/cron_error_report.txt
```

There is no error shown in the cron_error_report.txt either.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: please be aware there is a stackExchange site specifically for ubuntu. http://askubuntu.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer can help others. It really take a long time to figure it out.
I moved a file used for my current python program to a shared folder. I exported the shared folder to PYTHONPATH.

So there is no problem while I run the script in the command line. However, cron could not run it. So I have to move the file back to my current folder and the cron starts to work again.

Comment: Or better, copy the PYTHONPATH setting to a place where Cron can see it.  Traditionally, `.profile` is used for settings which should be shared between Bash and POSIX `sh` (which is what Cron runs).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure cron is running

> sudo service cron status

Comment: cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 1064: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: I would restart the cron service

Comment: I tried to restart the cron job ( I restart the server too) and two of them did not start automatically anyway (They work if I run them on the command line) . However, all three cron jobs worked before.  The only issue probably came from that  I updated the ubuntu automatically.

Comment: reset the cron service does not help at all. "cron start/running, process 11375" shows cron  is working, but did not execute my command.